# How reliable socket stream's flush() is?

Tags: java, android, networking, tcp

Consider this (simplified) piece of code:

```
public class Test {
    // assigned elsewhere
    InetSocketAddress socketAddress;
    String socketHost;
    int socketPort;
    Socket socket;

    int COMMAND = 10;
    int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10 * 1000;
    int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream  dis;

    protected void connect() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        socket.connect(socketAddress != null ? socketAddress : new InetSocketAddress(socketHost, socketPort), CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        socket.setSoTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    }

    void initializeDataStreams() throws IOException {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), socket.getSendBufferSize()));
        dis = new DataInputStream( new BufferedInputStream( socket.getInputStream(),  socket.getReceiveBufferSize()));
    }

    void run() {
        try {
            connect();
            initializeDataStreams();

            sendCommand(COMMAND, true);

            sendIdAndUsername(true);

            sendSyncPreference(true);

            sendBlockedIds(true);

            sendHeaders();

            // reading from 'dis' here
            // ...

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e){
            /* ... */
        }
    }

    void sendCommand(int command, boolean buffered) throws IOException {
        dos.write(command);
        if (!buffered) {
            dos.flush();
        }
    }

    void sendIdAndUsername(boolean buffered) throws IOException {
        sendId(true);  // always buffered
        String username = "user name";
        dos.writeBoolean(username != null);
        if (username != null) {
            dos.writeUTF(username);
        }
        if (!buffered) {
            dos.flush();
        }
    }

    void sendId(boolean buffered) throws IOException {
        dos.writeUTF("user id");
        if (!buffered) {
            dos.flush();
        }
    }

    void sendSyncPreference(boolean buffered) throws IOException {
        boolean fullSync = true;
        dos.writeBoolean(fullSync);
        if (!buffered) {
            dos.flush();
        }
    }

    void sendBlockedIds(boolean buffered) throws IOException {
        Set<String> blockedCrocoIds = new HashSet<>();

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(dos);
        oos.writeObject(blockedCrocoIds);
        if (!buffered) {
            oos.flush();
        }
    }

    private void sendHeaders() throws IOException {
        dos.writeUTF("some string");
        dos.writeInt(123);
        // some other writes...

        // this should flush everything, right?
        dos.flush();
    }
}
```

I left it intentionally with all the methods, just in case I've made some terribly obvious mistake there. When I execute Test.run(), *sometimes* (really hard to predict when exactly) it seems like the flush() in sendHeaders() doesn't work at all.

Server side doesn't receive anything on its ServerSocket.accept() for next 22 seconds (don't ask me where this number comes from, part of the mystery).

The idea was that I wont call flush() on every transmission but call it only once, to save the bandwidth.

So what's wrong with this code? How to ensure writes to my stream are reliable / immediate so the server can read it ASAP?

I also accept answer "there's nothing wrong", in that case it must be something which is being done in parallel and affecting the network stack on Android.

**EDIT:** Server code is really nothing special:

```
ListeningThread listeningThread = new ListeningThread();
listeningThread.start();
listeningThread.join();
```

and then:

```
public class ListeningThread extends Thread {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public ListeningThread() {
        try {
            // unbound server socket
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(NetworkUtil.APP_SERVER_PORT));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("run");

        while (serverSocket.isBound() && !isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new CommandThread(socket).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log(e);
            }
        }

        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
public class CommandThread extends Thread {
    private final Socket socket;

    public CommandThread(Socket socket) {
        log("CommandThread");

        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log("run");

        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(NetworkUtil.SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            int cmd = is.read(); // <========= so actually this is failing
            switch (cmd) {
                // handling of the command
                case COMMAND:
                    new DownloadMessagesThread(socket).start();
                break;
            }
        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, I'd open to agree on anything wrong with the object streams & co but the trouble is that I'm unable to reach (again, it's just sometimes, it's very random...) CommandThread's run(). So unless I'm missing something else, there's no way Object Streams could cause this kind of failure.

**EDIT 2:** Correction: it's not accept() I cannot reach, it's the first read operation:

> 03-07 11:22:42.965 00010 CommandThread: CommandThread
>
> 03-07 11:22:42.966 00108 CommandThread: run
>
> [... nothing happening ...]
>
> 03-07 11:23:04.549 00111 DownloadMessagesThread: run

Could this be caused by mixing the object stream and data stream after all?

Answer (score 3):

You should verify that the `ObjectOutputStream` creation in `sendBlockedIds` is not the culprit. 
I've already had some protocol "deadlocks" while mixing DataStreams and ObjectStreams, since the creation of the Writer/Reader pair of ObjectStreams implies a kind of handshake that may fail while mixing those streams.

EDIT: While reading again your question, I realized that I had not answered it. So yes, it is reliable. And +1 for EJP answer.

Comment: I suggest using some representation like JSON instead of sending binary objects.

Comment: I know what you mean, I had my share of pain with that as well. However, ObjectOutputStream's contructor just sends a few bytes over the stream, that's all. So even if there's some terrible error, it would at least reach accept() on the server side, wouldn't it?

Comment: If those few bytes are not flushed then the constructor of ObjectInputStream, on server side, will not exit in the timeout frame. We may need the server code to help you further.

Comment: @Xvolks: 100% agreed, this could lead to a problematic situation. But as mentioned, the server side doesn't even reach the point beyond accept(), therefore whatever could happen there, it doesn't get chance to do it, it's just as transmission never occurred on the client side until 22 seconds later (I have full logs from the service side so I can see it reaches the listener at that time...).

Comment: I've added server code anyway, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Why are you starting a second thread to handle the download case? What's wrong with the one you're in?

Comment: @EJP: nothing is wrong with it. It's just very old code, IIRC there was only one thread first and then the command thread was introduced and the transition 'thread -> runnable' (or whatever suitable) didn't happen. DownloadMessagesThread's constructor only assigns the socket and the server itself isn't definitely under heavy load at all.

Comment: Nothing is flushed on the line until the `sendHeaders()` call. You should really add an unconditional `flush()` just before the `new ObjectOutputStream()`

Comment: @Xvolks: True. But why would that pose a problem? I'm totally OK if there's everything sent in one 'bulk', the constructor just sends a couple of bytes as the object stream header, how is this different than sending my own ints/booleans/whatever?

Comment: You never call `flush()` on `ObjectOutputStream` so I think those bytes are stuck in the internal buffer of the `ObjectOutputStream` instance and never reach the underlying stream. This does not explain why the server cannot read the first byte.

Comment: It seems that sometimes it works, right ? Could it be that the garbage collector closes (and flush) the `ObjectOutputStream` before all your protocol deadlocks ?

Comment: @Xvolks: you may be onto something here. Thanks to EJP's relentless comments I checked `ObjectOutputStream` source and found out that this is exactly the case for primitive types (i.e. `ObjectOutputStream.writeUTF()` without flush() could have lost the string). For `writeObject()` I'm not completely sure (a lot of dark magic happening there) but it's worth a try because it would explain a lot. Will report back, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in your title, it is 100% reliable, as it doesn't do anything. Only the `flush()` methods of streams that are buffered actually do anything, and that only includes `ObjectOutputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`, and `PrintStream` depending on how you construct it. Not `DataOutputStream`, and not the output stream of the socket itself.

So in this case the only flush method that does anything is the buffered output stream's, and you can certainly rely on that, as it is just code, and has been working for twenty years.

If this is affecting the speed of `accept()`, there must be something odd about your accept loop that you haven't shown us: typically, doing I/O in the accept loop instead of in the started thread.

And you should certainly *not* create an `ObjectOutputStream` in the middle of the connection. Create it at the start and use it for everything, and an `ObjectInputStream` at the other end.

NB setting the buffer sizes to the socket buffer sizes respectively is really fairly pointless. The defaults are adequate.

Comment: The buffer size setting is not from my head, I saw it in Esmond Pitt's Fundamental Networking In Java, so I assumed he knows what he is doing. Any idea what could cause such a terrible delay in sending?

Comment: If I wrote that in FNIJ I retract it. What page? The delay can only be due to network conditions or effects, not your code. Most sends should only take a second or two, unless the receiver is very backed up and behind.

Comment: page 42, page 331, also in the available example source code provided with the book.

Comment: Wow. What was I thinking? Wrote most of that in about 2001-2: I must have 'refined' my ideas since then.

Comment: Ha, I had no idea it's you, what an interesting plot twist. ;-) The reason I'm not using ObjectOutputStream all the time is pretty dull -- a flaw in the original protocol design, sometimes those objects get extremely huge and Android kills the process with OOM exception because the ObjectOutputStream's cache takes all available memory (and trying to play with reset() looked like even more dangerous thing to do..). And now it's too late to change it.

Comment: Re-edited my answer & added more server code, you've helped me to realise it's not accept() after all but the first read operation. Not that it explains anything to me but maybe you guys see the problem already?

Comment: I'm back to network condtions on this one. Starting an `ObjectOutputStream` in the middle of the connection won't save any memory in this exchange. You do realise that it has `writeUTF()` and all the other `DataOutput` methods you're using?

Comment: You do also realise that `write(int)` won't actually *write* a value of 1000, and that `read()` won't ever return it? This code does not work *at all,* let alone in a timely fashion.

Comment: Yes, starting an ObjectOutputStream itself doesn't save memory but using DataOutputStream instead wherever possible *does* save memory, with each write via ObjectOutputStream a few KBs are allocated until reset() is called. And I'm writing a lot of data. It's not that I don't like ObjectOutputStream's writeUTF(). :-) About the write: 1000 is a (not very well chosen) example, in the production code I'm using numbers from 1 to 10 (constants), I'm going to fix it.

Comment: 'With each write via `ObjectOutputStream` a few KBs are allocated' is only true *when you call `writeObject()`*, and it isn't 'a few Kbs', it is a single slot in a hash map. If you call `writeUTF()`, `writeInt()`, etc. there is no memory usage at all. Posting code that isn't the real code is futile.

Comment: I should have been more precise. This *is* the real code. It's just I was lazy to look up the actual 'command' value used and made up this '1000' (not very wise, now I see why...). As you can see, all the other constants (timeouts etc) and constructions are intact, as in the real code. Thanks for the hint about `writeUTF()`, I have never realized that and will definitely use `ObjectOutputStream` all the way down here. However, is there any reason to believe this could have caused the delay?

Comment: Actually, you're not 100% correct about `ObjectOutputStream`. For `writeObject()` it may be a "single slot in a hash map" but all primitive types are cached in an internal buffer, therefore if using `write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)` with 200 x 1 MB writes, there's 200 MB allocated internally unless I do `flush()` after every write (which decreases performance). And since `reset()` does the internal flush as well, I thought the OOMs are caused by the internal hash map while this was the true cause. `DataOutputStream` does not use an internal buffer.

Comment: @MiroKropacek What internal buffer? There is a 1K temporary write buffer, similar to a `BufferedOutputStream`, which is only used some of the time. The suggestion that `write(byte[], int, int)` caches anything is completely incorrect.

Comment: I saw this coming so I've created a nice proof for you: http://pastebin.com/EjJLK0tx ... pay attention on line 621, "primitiveTypes" is a `DataOutputStream` backed by `ByteArrayOutputStream`. And this buffer is flushed in `drain()` which is in turn called (among other places) in `reset()` and `flush()`. This is standard Android SDK. Do you still think my claim is "completely incorrect"?

Comment: Well I am gobsmacked. I've been reading the serialization code for twenty years and never seen anything like that. The incompetent moron, and I am choosing my words carefully, who wrote that drivel needs his head examined. All that was needed was a `BufferedOutputStream` temporarily wrapped around the target stream. Fortunately you can get around it by writing in 8k chunks and flushing them yourself.